# install pyqt IDE

Tags: python, ide, qt4, pyqt

I installed python 2.7 and pyqt4 and downloaded eric4 IDE, but cant install it because it says i am missing pyqt4.qtcore. How can I fix that? I use Windows 7

This is the console output when I try to install eric4:

> C:\Users\username\Desktop\eric4-4.5.7>python install.py
>
> Checking dependencies
>
> Python Version: 2.6.5
>
> Sorry, please install PyQt4.
>
> Error: No module named PyQt4.QtCore

Comment: Did you download the version of PyQt for Python 2.7 from Riverbank or build it yourself? http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/download

Comment: For one, you're running the command under python-2.6.5 (see the message above.  I'd hazard a guess that you need to specify the complete path here.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python-qt4`

Comment: @X.Jacobs judging from the path the user is running Windows.

Comment: for windows checkout [How to install PyQt 4.3 on Windows](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2007/01/how-to-install-pyqt-41-python-25-and-qt_8340/)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you installed PyQt4 and python 2.7 correctly.
If python 2.7 was installed latest, it should be the default.
Otherwise use an explicit file path, for instance

```
D:\python27\python.exe
```

and check if it says "python 2.7" when you run it in the shell.

Note that the PyQt4 has the python version in its downloaded installer or archive filename.
(how did you actually install it?)

If PyQt4 is correctly installed, then this should work, so please try that first:

```
>>> from PyQt4 import QtCore
```

After that all works, run the install script, and *use the right python version*
in the way I showed above.